# Is any Windows simulator available to test iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, windows, ios-simulator

Is there any windows simulator availabe through which I can test (only testing) my iPhone application on Windows XP?

Thanks & regards,

Khushi

Comment: Yes, it would be interesting to know why the asker wants to do this, as it doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: @Mark: he has Windows XP machine as his development box and wants to test an iPhone app he's developing rather than keying into the iPhone itself all day.

Answer (score 12):

No.  The iPhone Simulator is available as part of the iPhone SDK, which is only available for Mac OS X Leopard on Intel-based Macs.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a physical iOS device, you can test your app on Windows with [SeeTest](http://experitest.com/automation/).

You connect your device to your Windows machine and then you can perform Web/Native tests, record it and play it again.