# Testing native mobile apps

Tags: iphone, emulation

I am testing a native mobile app that has been developed for the iPhone, and I am trying to find an emulator that will run on Windows. I have found a lot of emulators, but their description is for mobile web apps, but the app that I am testing, and will be testing, is for native apps. Does anyone know of an iPhone emulator for Windows to test native apps?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [Is any Windows simulator available to test iPhone application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311119/is-any-windows-simulator-available-to-test-iphone-application)

Answer (score 4):

Nope. There's no such program out there currently. If you're doing iOS development, you more or less need an Intel-based Mac.

Comment: You just need to be running OSX -- which you can do on some non Apple-PCs.  You'll need to dual boot or run in a VM.

Comment: Well, that would certainly qualify as one. ;)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible as Native Apps are specifically for them, platforms.
If you would like to develop multi-platform app, i would advise a Mobile Web Application.

Answer (score 1):

SeeTest enables you to connect IOS emulators and to test native applications.
See here: http://experitest.com/studio/help2/WebHelp/Connect_iPhone_emulator1.htm

Answer (score 0):

No solution for that to my knowledge. The only way I can think of would be to use Hackintosh with Xcode.