# Is there any iPhone simulator for windows?

Tags: iphone, ios, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to run an IPA file in an iPhone simulator on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585076/is-it-possible-to-run-an-ipa-file-in-an-iphone-simulator-on-windows)

I spent enough time searching that is there any iPhone simulator for windows? I saw  number of threads in StackOverFlow and other blogs but did not found accepted answer.

I need iPhone simulator for windows to which i can install IPA for testing.

Comment: Numerous duplicates, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585076/is-it-possible-to-run-an-ipa-file-in-an-iphone-simulator-on-windows and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311119/is-any-windows-simulator-available-to-test-iphone-application?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **no**. You need to have (Mac) OS X to run the iPhone Emulator. You can try to install OS X on a PC (via Virtual Machine or "hackintosh") though.

Answer (score 0):

what usually do is 
install Machine emulator in your windows
then install MacOS in virtual machine for test.